# Kohana cURL sent data is empty

Tags: php, curl, kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm sending data using cURL on the following code block:

```
$content = $data['email'].'|'.$data['limit'].'|'.$data['docs'];

$curl = curl_init(ACCESS_URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$answer = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

The webservice side do run and creates the file, but $_POST is empty. I just can't figure out why.

```
public function action_getAccess() {
    file_put_contents('/home/donut/uploads/data.txt', $_POST);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From curl:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/plain"));
```

And catch this as:

```
file_put_contents('/home/donut/uploads/data.txt', file_get_contents("php://input"));
```